# Firebase - Can't run tests against standalone test project

Tags: android, testing, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I'm investigating a cloud-based solution for our UIAutomator 2.0 testing needs, and I'm having quite a few issues with uploading APKs for our test project.

We have a stand-alone test project that exists separately from the main Android application project. The package for the project is in the format com.company.project and the package for the test project is com.company.project.test.

1) If I attempt to upload a test APK that has all the tests in androidTest (and the gradle uses androidTestCompile for dependencies), Firebase console complains that:

```
"Unable to find instrumentation package for com.company.project.test"
```

This is likely because our test project is standalone, and the tests actually live under com.company.project.test.test.

2) On the other hand, if I change the location of tests to java main folder in the project and change androidTestCompile to compile for the gradle dependencies, when I attempt to upload the test APK Firebase console complains again:

```
"We experienced an error while validating your APK. Please verify the APK is correct and upload again."
```

I can't get a single test running since I'm blocked both ways.

Anyone else attempt to use Firebase Test Lab with a similar project hierarchy? Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. Don't even bother with the web UI, use the gcloud terminal to run your tests instead. It's WAY more customizable.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firebase/test/android/run

You can specify the --test-package to whatever your test package is, whether it's a standalone project or not.